# Issue when using pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

When I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 17
#define NUMTHREADS 4

struct ThreadData {
    int start, stop;
    int* array;
};

/* puts i^2 into array positions i=start to stop-1 */
void* squarer(struct ThreadData* td) {
    struct ThreadData* data=(struct ThreadData*) td;
    int start=data->start;
    int stop=data->stop;
    int* array=data->array;
    int i;

    for (i=start; i<stop; i++) {
        array[i]=i*i;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    int array[ARRAYSIZE];
    pthread_t thread[NUMTHREADS];
    struct ThreadData data[NUMTHREADS];
    int i;
    /*
        this has the effect of rounding up the number of tasks
        per thread, which is useful in case ARRAYSIZE does not
        divide evenly by NUMTHREADS.
    */
    int tasksPerThread=(ARRAYSIZE+NUMTHREADS-1)/NUMTHREADS;

    /* Divide work for threads, prepare parameters */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        data[i].start=i*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].stop=(i+1)*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].array=array;
    }
    /* the last thread must not go past the end of the array */
    data[NUMTHREADS-1].stop=ARRAYSIZE;

    /* Launch Threads */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, squarer , &data[i]);
    }

    /* Wait for Threads to Finish */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    /* Display Result */
    for (i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, *squarer, &data[i]);
>                                          ^

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: and what does the rest of the error say?

Comment: `pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, *squarer, &data[i]);` That code shown in the error message is not the same as the code that you have shown in the question. Make sure you are compiling what you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter passed to [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) has to be of type `void * (*)(void *)`.

Yours is of type `void * (*)(struct ThreadData * td)`.

To fix this change

```
void* squarer(struct ThreadData* td) {
  struct ThreadData* data=(struct ThreadData*) td;
```

to become

```
void* squarer(void * td) {
  struct ThreadData * data = td;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `squarer` has type `void *(*)(struct ThreadData *)`, but `pthread_create` expects an arguments of type `void *(*)(void *)`.  Those types are incompatible.

Change your function to take a `void *` argument, then assign it to a `struct ThreadData *`.

```
void* squarer(void *td) {
    struct ThreadData* data=td;
    ....
```